# Returning an array of structs from a function - C programming

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

So I'm trying to write a function that will return an array of several values. At the moment, it is running correctly but only outputting the final calculated value. How would I make it so the output includes all calculated values?

My code looks like this:

```
//Practice to output an array of structs

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct boat_params {
    double V, Uc, Vc;
    };

struct boat_params submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H) {

    struct boat_params volume;

    double V_sub, Uc_sub, Vc_sub;
    V_sub = 0;

    //Boat description
    double C, delta;
    double theta, theta_rad, theta_min, theta_min2, theta_lim, theta_lim2, theta_lim_deg;
    double Ug1, Ug2, Vg1, Vg2, V1, V2;
    double pi; 

    pi = 4*atan(1);
    C = sqrt(L1*L1 + L2*L2);
    delta = acos(L1/C);

    theta_lim = asin(H/L1);
    theta_lim_deg = (theta_lim/pi) * 180.0;
    theta_min = asin(H/C) - delta; 
    theta_min2 = 0;

    //Calculating the submerged volume and centre of gravity for each different angle
    for (theta = 0; theta <= 10; theta ++) {

    //**Note: I've taken out the actual calculations of V_sub, Uc_sub, and Vc_sub for brevity**


        volume.V = V_sub;
        volume.Uc = Uc_sub;
        volume.Vc = Vc_sub;
        }


    return volume; 

    }


int main () {

double L1, L2, Lavg, H;
struct boat_params volume; 

L1 = 17.6; 
L2 = 3; 
Lavg = 4;
H = 4.5;

volume = submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H);

printf("V = %lf\nUc = %lf\nVc = %lf\n", volume.V, volume.Uc, volume.Vc);

return 0;

}
```

I can get it to correctly output the last calculated value (for theta = 10) but that's the only value I'm getting. How would I calculate V_sub, Uc_sub, and Vc_sub for each theta value? and output each value. I'm assuming this means turning the struct into an array and filling each element of the array with values of the struct for that theta but I don't know how to do this!

I really appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

**Also: If possible I'd like to avoid pointers but understand this may not be possible! I'm still very new and not good at using them!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite right, you will need to have an array for that. If the number of elements in the  array is constant, you could also create a struct that contains exactly that number elements, but please don't do that.
To operate on arrays you will - unfortunately - need pointers. A very common way to do this in C is not to return a pointer, but pass a 'result' pointer in. This means that it will be up to the user of the function to allocate space and free it, he can also use the syntax for arrays. In your code it seems that the number of values is constant, this makes the aforementioned solution possible. Alternatively you could allocate space on the heap (using `malloc`) and return a pointer, but that means the user needs to free memory he never allocated, counter intuitive and might result in memory leaks if he forgets to do so. Consider the following solution:

```
void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct boat_params *result) {
    // your calculations here
    for (theta = 0; theta <= 10; theta ++) {
        (result+theta)->V = V_sub;
        (result+theta)->Uc = Uc_sub;
        (result+theta)->Vc = Vc_sub;
    }
}

// somewhere in your code where you want to use your function
struct boat_params values[11];
unsigned char i = 0;
submerged_values(/* parameters */, values);
for (; i <= 10; ++i) {
    printf("V = %lf\nUc = %lf\nVc = %lf\n", values[i].V, values[i].Uc, values[i].Vc);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `values` not `&values`

Comment: You are quite right, I don't know what was going on in my head at that point.

Comment: I haven't seen the result+theta syntax before... what is this? or is this just incremental?

Comment: Ok just going through this a bit more (sorry it took me a while!). A few things I want to clarify... where you're calling the struct is as an input to the function. Is this the same as what I've done in my code? Also, would I not need to use the counter (i) and the printf statement inside my theta for loop to print the calculated value before it gets re-assigned?

Comment: Result is a pointer here, so `result+theta` is also a pointer. Pointer airthmetic in C makes sure it is the `theta`th value in the array to whose first element the pointer points. It is equivalent to `result[theta].V = V_sub;`. I'm not really sure why I chose the different syntax, feel free to use whatever feels right to you.

Comment: No, this is different from what you do. You create a struct in your function and then return that struct. What my code does is allocate memory for 11 of your structs in the *caller's* (not the callee's) stack. It then passes a pointer to this. This way the function can populate the array with calculated values. In your theta-loop values are not reassigned, because in each new iteration `(result+theta)`points to a new memory location. The values are then printed after the function call in their own loop.

Comment: Ok so in the part of your example that uses result+theta, etc... that would go inside my theta for loop. And then the i (counter) loop is simply to print the values? Sorry for all of the questions, just want to make sure I really understand it!

Comment: Sorry so the result+theta is in place of my volume.V, etc?

Comment: No worries, this is what this site is for. You got it right, the `(result+theta)->` is the replacement for your `volume.`. And the `i`-loop is used exclusively to print all the values. It does nothing else. Just loop over the array and execute your `printf` for every struct. Pointer's are a hurdle you just need to fight through ;)

Comment: yeah I know... Just having such a hard time imagining what they do exactly! Thanks a lot for your help, I'll see if I can do it!

Comment: Sorry last thing! Where you've put the section after //somewhere in your code, say the printf statement, would that need to go into my main or does it matter? Can it be part of the function?

Comment: In your case it would go in the main function. It goes where the function is called. You could also print the results in the function itself, but I strongly advise against it! Btw. if you find my answer helpful, why don't you upvote as well ;)

Comment: ok so when I do that, I get this error: invalid operands to binary expression ('struct boat_params' and 'double')... any ideas about that?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, I'm in the middle of a meeting ;) Can you post your full code on pastebin and give a specific line?

Comment: I assume that you didn't pass a pointer, but an actual struct. And you need to change `theta` to an integer type, in your case `unsigned char` should work fine. You can't add a double to a pointer and while doubles can obviously hold integers, I recommend you always choose the 'most restrictive' type.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it.. How do I share it with you on pastebin? No worries at all, no rush unless it's more interesting than your meeting

Comment: You can simply create a public paste and share the link here in the comment section, but as SO kindly suggests, this should be moved to a chat... Will do now. Nope, I won't. Appearantly you don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Yeah sorry I did try to move it before but I'm still too new to this site. Apologies! 

Here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/EzA8mTSp

Comment: You were doing exactly what I thought you were. Here, I fixed your code: http://pastebin.com/7q2z3Mhg. I changed `theta` to an `unsigned char` and changed the signature so that an argument is actually passed. You only had `struct boat_params`, but that's just a type, you need a pointer to that type and it needs a name: `struct boat_params *results`. And then you don't need to declare your volume struct, because you're passing it in. The code now compiles fine for me on both gcc and clang.

Comment: brilliant, thanks a lot, you've been a huge help. Last question though! Would I not need to change the types of all my theta values? Or just theta?

Comment: Changing just `theta` is sufficient. After skimming your code it seems the other values need to be floating point numbers for what they do. `theta`, however, is really just an index and can be an integer for that reason. That will most likely even make your code faster! Here it needs to be an integer, because pointer arithmetic is only possible with integers, e.g. you can't add half a byte to an address ;)

Comment: never mind, got it now! Sorry for the chat in the page, hopefully my rating will go up soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add your logic to the loop and maths:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRSIZE 100

typedef struct boat_params {
  double  V, Uc, Vc;
} Volume;

struct boat_params submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, Volume *volumes[]) {
  double theta;

  int i = 0; /* only example, change as needed */
  Volume *p;
  for (theta = 0; theta <= 10; theta ++) {
    p = malloc(sizeof(* p)); 
    if (p == NULL) {
      printf("malloc failed to allocate a new space");
      exit(0);
    }                   

    p->V = 1; //V_sub;
    p->Uc = 2; //Uc_sub;
    p->Vc = 3; //Vc_sub;

    volumes[i] = p;
    i++;
  }

}


int main () {
  double L1, L2, Lavg, H;

  L1 = 17.6; 
  L2 = 3; 
  Lavg = 4;
  H = 4.5;

  Volume *volumes[ARRSIZE];

  submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H, volumes);
  printf("V = %lf\nUc = %lf\nVc = %lf\n", volumes[0]->V, volumes[0]->Uc, volumes[0]->Vc); /* first element for example */

  return 0;
}
```

If you don't know the size of the volumes array in advance, you should consider using linked list.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your code does not return any array, it pots the values in a global array.  Also, don't cast malloc.

Comment: Thank you! I got it and fixed.